# Декодирование текста из строки

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

Имеются строки похожие на эту `"u0410u043bu0435u043au0441u0435u0439" ("Алексей")`

Возможно ли преобразовать данные строки в нормальный текст?

Comment: А как такие строки у вас получились?

Comment: Получились при парсинге сайта

Comment: Или с кодировкой парсера напутали, или их так получаете?

Comment: Вроде не напутал, они исходно такие

Comment: если вы на самом деле пытаетесь из html достать json данные зашитые в javascript код, то это [XY-задача](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
text = 'u0410u043bu0435u043au0441u0435u0439'
print(text)

# Сначала приводим строку в правильный вид, после конвертируем строку в байты,
# и декодируем байтовую строку, используя специаальный кодек unicode-escape
new_text = text.replace('u', '\\u').encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape')
print(new_text)
# Алексей
```

Про `unicode-escape` можно [тут прочитать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings)

---

Попробовал решить костыль другим костылем:

```
import re

text = 'My name is u0410u043bu0435u043au0441u0435u0439! Auuu!'
print(text)

for uchar in set(re.findall(r'u[a-f0-9]{4}', text)):
    text = text.replace(uchar, '\\u' + uchar[1:])

new_text = text.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape')
print(new_text)
# My name is Алексей! Auuu!
```

Comment: В английских словах исчезли буквы u

Comment: @Fabriziog, вот что случается, когда одним костылем приходится другой решать :) Вот текущая ваша проблема решена, но появилось другая

Comment: @Fabriziog, если я ответил на ваш вопрос, то отметьте его как решенным: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)